# Online learning with CDN broken references

Tags: angularjs, google-cdn

I tried to access the documentation pages for *AngularJS*:

- http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial
- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/

But I noticed that the script links are broken and the page gets also broken because of that.
Is there any alternative resource for the interactive documentation?

*Note*

*It seems that with the exception of the home page, which uses `1.2.0`:*

```
Request URL:http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
```

*the links are broken on most of the pages of the official website.*

```
Request URL:http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

*There's also an entry in the official issue tracker: [http://docs.angularjs.org/ referring to a non existent version of angular from google CDN.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4966)*

Comment: Same problem, attempted viewing ng-switch, homepage, learn page etc. All as described above. It looks like it's been raised: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4966

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every bit of documentation you need is in [the Angular source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src):

Angular methods are *very* well documented. For example, if (like the comment) you wanted to view the docs for ng-switch. You can go to:

> src->directives->ngSwitch.js

That's give you all the documentation, usage examples and more *plus* the relevant source code which is worth reading.

You can also go to /docs/ for the actual documentation but it's not as nice imo :)